# Extra Large Table Effects Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I inherited a database (don't we all just love that) and a table has grown out of control.

The database is over 50 GB.
I did a defrag on it as well as re-indexing but that did not help.
The problem is that the table has 236 columns and about 23000 rows.
And no, that is not a typo!

The only solution I can see is to break up the table.
The .Net app is on our intranet and I have optimized every piece of code it contains as well as the stored procedures.

The table contains information such as TempHigh, TempLow, and TempMed. The High, Low, and Med repeat throughout the table for other factors. So each High, Low, and Med will become its own table with a foreign key pointing to the parent table.

This will create a lot of JOINs when accessing the data and updating.

This is the only way I can see that may fix the problem.

My question is, am I overlooking a better way to fix this problem?

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!!!

**EDIT**

Just to clarify, I have run a defrag on the database as well as re-indexing.
I have had performance monitor open on the web and db servers as well.

Thanks for the comments. I will try to answer your questions. First, I have copied the database to my .Net development environment and it's slow, even with just me logging in. And moved the .Net app to the same server as the sql server to test connection issues. Same problems. This is a transaction system (OLTP). Some columns I have already moved to their own tables as they were repeating themselves and in their place a new column with a foreign key (without the constraint). There are no images, just data.

Here are the specs of the table:

```
TableName   SchemaName  RowCounts   TotalSpaceKB    UsedSpaceKB UnusedSpaceKB
MyTable         dbo       22904       45192            45160        32
```

Comment: With **your** data, and **your** data structures, make the change in a non-live environment and *test* the results. Performance tuning over the internet without access to any data doesn't work.

Comment: What is the type of columns? Can that be optimized? 23000*236 is 5428000, 5,428 thousand datapoints should fit well within 50 GB.

Comment: 23000 rows and 50gb of data? do you have some images in there or columns with a LOT of data? maybe you could do some vertical partitioning, create 1:1 relations to new tables, and move there some of the heaviest columns. difficult to say without more data

Comment: is this a database for an OLAP application? If it is then dont break down your schema and add appropriate indexes to aid your queries, if this is an OLTP application, consider archiving some of data, Breaking down into smaller tables and only keep the data in this database required on daily basis, the rest should be archived or in an OLAP database where loads of indexes will help the query to be executed.

Comment: How is each row averaging over 2mb with temperature data? What is the actual table definition?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will try to answer your questions. First, I have copied the database to my .Net development environment and it's slow, even with just me logging in. And moved the .Net app to the same server as the sql server to test connection issues. Same problems. This is a transaction system (OLTP). Some columns I have already moved to their own tables as they were repeating themselves and in their place a new column with a foreign key (without the constraint). There are no images, just data.

Comment: The temperature data is just an example. It goes further than that such as Nylon1H, Nylon1M, Nylon1L, Nylon2H..... you get the idea. Most columns are floats, ints, or nvarchar and a few datetime.

Comment: It doesn't sound like 23,000 rows should occupy that much disk space.  Check the query from this answer to see the actual space used by your table:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/55374/10832

Comment: Edited my question with the table info.

Comment: 45,000 Kb is approx 45 Mb. Much less than 1Gb...

Comment: 45,192 KB is only 45 MB. Smaller than tiny in the DB world.

Comment: You both are absolutely correct. I fixed my question to read the database is over 50GB. But this is the table that most people access and effects performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> am I overlooking a better way to fix this problem?

Yes:

- Profile your application (source code, not SQL) to ensure that the DB access is the slowest part
- Run SQL traces to identify the worst-performing queries and work with a good DBA to identify possible optimizations
- Make sure all statistics are up-to-date (at least daily).
- Don't guess - use hard facts to identify performance bottlenecks
- Make sure you have the appropriate indexes for the most common queries.
- Don't assume that breaking up the table will speed things up.  It can actually make things *slower* if you're constantly joining across multiple tables that are 1:1.

I've seen databases that are *terabytes* in size that still perform well (adding/uptating thousands of records daily).  The key is determining the *slowest* operations and adding/updating indexes to optimize those.

Comment: Marked this as an answer because it may help others. After configuring another server with more resources, the problem persists. Even with an application that connects to a small table with about 1500 records. Runs great if browsing in IIS but even on the prod server and opening IE, it gets bottle necked somewhere. At least I am now sure it is not the database.

Comment: @Zath - it sounds like your problem is then either in translating the raw data to your model and/or rendering it on the client side.

Comment: I found the problem line of code. IPHostEntry FullEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(REMOTE_ADDR); When browsing in IIS using local host, loads great. Go to the server browser to the ip address, it takes forever to load. At least I narrowed it down further. Maybe the DNS server. Time to post another question here after some more research and testing...